# How do I set a css class for some nodes of TreeView, in CodeBehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, treeview

I want to style **some nodes** differently, in codebehind.

In my `TreeView`, parents have two types of children. One type is same as the parent type (for example organizationalUnit) and the other type is not (for example organizationalMembers).

I want to show these two types with different styles.

Comment: please expand on your question: what aspect of tree view do you want to style? are you looking to customize the tree-view as a whole or make some rows different than others?

Comment: as I told, i want to make some nodes different than others.

Comment: What do you have so far ?

Comment: I hope this explanation helps. Each level of the tree-view gets its own class attribute. This allows you to customize entire levels, but not unfortunately, no more granular than that.

Comment: a little advice for the future: 1) do a little of your own research before posting to stack. 2) try to post your question with a little accuracy. 3) have a good attitude toward ppl who try to help. They probably won't try again.

Answer (score 3):

I don't get the nasty comments - there is actually not an obvious solution to this as TreeNode has neither a `CssClass` nor a `style` attribute (a design oversight IMHO).

I had this **exact** need and solved it by encasing the TreeNode's "text" in a span with class and/or style attributes. I say "text" because you'd *think* that `TreeNode.Text` would be the HTML element's innertext, but by experimentation I find that if you set `node.Text` to HTML that it will (unexpectedly) render as the supplied HTML (ie sets innerhtml).

So, for example,

```
TreeNode tn = new TreeNode("<span style='color:red;'>ABC</span>");
```

will indeed render red text (as opposed to showing the words "span" etc).
Again, unexpected, but it does work.
And, again, I'd have expected TreeNode to have (in addition to `CssClass` and/or `style` attrs) perhaps a `node.Html` attr for setting innerhtml and let `node.Text` set innertext. 
Maybe MSFT assigned TreeNode to a jr programmer :)

This solved it for me, hope it helps others.